# Laravel Carbon See if date is in the past

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am very confused by this, maybe its something simple I am not seeing. If I want to see if a date is in the past of today I should be able to do something like this?

```
if( $league->date_start <= Carbon::now() ){
    $join  = false;
    $message = 'Sorry, the league has already started';
}
```

if I dump out the dates its

```
$league->date_start = 2017-07-31 00:00:00
Carbon::now() = 2017-11-01 16:29:27
```

`$league->date_start` is a protected date so its a carbon instance

But this doesnt work, if I switch it to `$league->date_start >= Carbon::now()` it works and wont let me join. I know the "league" start date is in the past so shouldnt it be `$league->date_start <= Carbon::now()`?????

Answer (score 131, accepted):

There's built-in Carbon method `isPast` so you can use:

```
$league->date_start->isPast()
```

to determine if date is in past or not

Comment: Source: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.28.0/src/Carbon/Traits/Comparison.php#L497

Comment: The question asks if it is past from today, not if it is in the past in general.

Answer (score 7):

To check wether if `$date` lies in a (day greater or equal than today) OR (day before today) use :

```
 function isPast($date){ 

    return  Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->gte($date);

 }


  // true :  $date is in past

  // false:  $date is in today or future
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the section “Comparison” on [carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). You should call `$first->lte($second)` to compare two carbon instances.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Technically mine worked too, there was just a bad chuck of code that was blocking it

Answer (score 2):

Try using `if ($league->date_start->diffInSeconds() >= 0)`. The method `diffInSeconds` returns the difference between the current time and your carbon instance.

Here's an example of an output from tinker -

```
>>> $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
=> Carbon\Carbon {#648
     +"date": "2017-11-01 16:41:04.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
>>> $now->diffInSeconds();
=> 5
>>> $now->diffInSeconds();
=> 7
>>> $now->diffInSeconds();
=> 8
>>> $now->diffInSeconds();
=> 10
>>> $now->diffInSeconds() > 0
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

The Basic idea behind comparing dates with Carbon is that both the dates must has to be in Carbon format, in your case `Carbon::now()` is but `$league->date_start` is not, which can be converted by using `Carbon::parse()`

There are many ways by which this can be achieved :

- By using `<=` :

```
if(Carbon::parse($league->date_start) <= Carbon::now()){
    $join  = false;
    $message = 'Sorry, the league has already started';
}
```

- by using `lte` :

```
if(Carbon::parse($league->date_start)-> lte(Carbon::now()){
    $join  = false;
    $message = 'Sorry, the league has already started';
}
```

- by using `lessThanOrEqualTo` :

```
if(Carbon::parse($league->date_start)->lessThanOrEqualTo(Carbon::now()){
    $join  = false;
    $message = 'Sorry, the league has already started';
}
```