# Issue while comparing datetime

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am trying to compare two datetimes.

```
$expiry = strtotime($actualprice->created_at);
if($expiry < strtotime('now'))
```

The above if condition calculates false. What is the issue? BTW my default timezone is UTC. My question is not about how to compare datetimes. Its the issue with comparison I am asking about.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059484/laravel-carbon-see-if-date-is-in-the-past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `created_at` is automatically converted to a [Carbon instance](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) by Eloquent, you can use the `isPast()` and `isFuture()` methods:

```
if ($actualprice->created_at->isPast()) // Is expired?
if ($actualprice->created_at->isFuture()) // Is not expired?
```

You if want to set the timezone before that, do something like this:

```
$actualprice->created_at->timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
```

Comment: using isPast directly on created_at without using Carbon::parse didn't worked for me. Also if(Carbon::parse($actualprice->created_at)->isPast()) equals to false.

Comment: @Yojan do you use Eloquent? Please show result of `dd($actualprice->created_at)`

Comment: "2018-02-26 14:13:19"

Comment: @Yojan so you don't use Eloquent. `parse` will work for you then. You've said you're using the default timezone which is UTC, so `isPast()` will work for you. It will return `false` because current UTC time is `2018-02-26 09:55:00` and the `2018-02-26 14:13:19` date in not past.

Comment: Thank you that explains the if condition. But I do use Eloquent. And what should I do to check if the date has expired or not?

Comment: @Yojan if you want `created_at` automatically be converted into a Carbon instance, please show the query you're using and the `$dates` property from the model if you've overridden it. The `if()` code I've shown in the answer will check if the date is expired or not. The date you've shown is not expired, so the `isPast()` will return `false`. If you want to check if the date is not expired, use the `isFuture()` method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Here is the query `Coupons::where('code', '=', $code)->first();` and I do not have $dates property but I have set `$timestamps=false`. I think setting `$timestamps=false` might be the issue.

Comment: @Yojan yes, that's the issue. You need to remove it.

Comment: Setting `$timestamps=false` was the issue. Thank you very much.